# ubuntu java error

Tags: java, eclipse

java --version returns

```
java: error while loading shared libraries: libjli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

and while running eclipse it returns a dialogue box with message

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=127
/usr/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-jar /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.4.0.v20140925-0400/splash.bmp
-launcher /opt/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-    1326/eclipse_1605.so
-startup /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata 618010
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
-vm /usr/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-jar /opt/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
```

I am using ubuntu 14.04
Anybody can help on this please?

Answer (score 0):

you can find this file in your java folder "jli/libjli.so" or can you past output of following command.

$ ldd java

so that you will know the missing libraries for that binary.